# Qt QScreen::physicalSize returns incorrect values

Tags: qt, size, screen

I use `QSizeF QScreen::physicalSize()` to determine whether target device is tablet or mobile. But the method returns incorrect values. I use `Samsung GT-I8190`, which has width ~52.2 and height ~87.1 millimeters. But the method returns 76 and 127 millimeters relatively. Tried to google about this problem, but no result. Who has this problem, what's the matter?

Comment: > http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#physicalSize-prop
Qt gets this info from the device. I've looked up this device on amazon and converted the the size to milimiters, it is ALMOST the size you report, 121.92 millimeters x 63.5 millimeters. My guess is that this device is not reporting the screen size but the screen size plus a border or something like this.

Comment: it looks like you specified the phone BODY size, but not SCREEN one

Comment: @Constantine Not  Túlio, but that's what the device's implementers did. The device itself provides wrong size to Qt, there's nothing that Qt can do to fix that :( You'd have the same problem if you were coding directly for Android.

Comment: @KubaOber, I supposed, that it's namely Qt framework problem but not device's implementers. But now I'm not sure. Anyway, other developers' programmes for my Nexus 4 CM12 determine correctly mobile or tablet. But my programme, written with Qt framework.

Comment: There's a slight possibility that Qt queries the size in a wrong way. You'd need to try running a small android app first to query the screen size and see if you get the right results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [physicalDotsPerInchX](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#physicalDotsPerInchX-prop) and [physicalDotsPerInchY](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#physicalDotsPerInchY-prop) to calculate the pixel size.

Then use [availableSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#availableSize-prop) to get the screen size in pixels and multiple the width and height by their respective pixel size(that you calculated).

I would like to code and test this approach but I can't right now.